# How to use 'Set Style' in draw.io's online tools 'Create Custom Link' to change 'fillColor'?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am using the online tool of `Draw.io` [Create Custom Link](https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/link.html) to change a normal object such as a square's `fillColor`. Where

1. Action for Cell(s): `Set Style`; Key: `fillcolor`; Value: `#ffe6cc`
2. Tags:`ss`
   push the `Add Action` button, you can get the code in `Custom Link:`

```
data:action/json,{
  "actions": [
    {
      "style": {
        "tags": [
          "ss"
        ],
        "key": "#ffe6cc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this one do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably half of the (currently) 54 views.  I had the same question/problem.
Looking at the json in the Action, if you have a 'key', you need a 'value'.  The tool doesn't seem to add the 'value' field like it should.  You can manually add the value like this:

```
data:action/json,{
  "actions": [
    {
      "style": {
        "cells": [
          "ss"
        ],
        "key": "fillColor",
        "value": "#ffe6cc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, when I went to check the 'Create Custom Link' page, now it inserts the value for you correctly.